# How do I perform an action after a user saves an options menu in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, menu, hook

I have a Wordpress plugin in which I added a menu that allows a user to set various options.  I used the "add_menu_page" function described here - http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_menu_page .  I now need to do some actions AFTER the options on this page have been saved, but I'm not sure if I can do that or, if I can, what hooks to use.

I can't post exactly the code I'm using to create this options page, but I'll try and put together something similar to get the message across

```
function my_menu_page() {
    add_menu_page('My Menu', 'My Menu', 'edit_posts', "my_menu_settings", "my_menu_settings");
}

function my_menu_settings() {
    echo "          
        <h1>My Menu Settings</h1>
        <div>
            <form action='options.php' method='post' name='options'>
            " . wp_nonce_field('update-options') . "
                <input type='text' name='my_option_1' value='" . get_option('my_option_1') . "' /><br />
                <input type='hidden' name='action' value='update' />
                <input type='hidden' name='page_options' value='my_option_1' />     
                <input type='submit' name='Submit' value='Update' />
            </form>
        </div>
    ";
}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_menu_settings');
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you are looking for something like **update_option**, [here is the link to the Wordpress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/update_option/)

Here are a few variations of the same hook:
(update_option can be used also to save/create new options)

**update_option_{option_name}**: Runs after the option with name "option_name" has been updated. For example, for the option with name "foo":

```
add_action('update_option_foo', 'my_menu_settings', 10, 2);
```

**update_option**: Runs before an option gets updated. Example:

```
add_action('update_option', 'my_menu_settings', 10, 3);
```

**updated_option**: Runs after an an option has been updated. Example:

```
add_action('updated_option', 'my_menu_settings', 10, 3);
```

Thanks

Comment: Do these fire when the actual sidebar page is updated or the ACF field group is updated?

Comment: According to the documentation "Fires immediately before an option value is updated", so when any option value is updated including the value mentioned by you. you can always try it

Comment: so not when the options page itself is updated. I have tried but it doesn't seem to fire. Maybe I am naming it wrong, not 100% what the name foo is referring to.

Comment: 'foo' is a generic option name, lets say that you create an option name called "headerSize",  in this case `add_action('update_option_headerSize', 'my_menu_settings', 10, 2);
` the function my_menu_settings will be fired when headerSize will be updated.
you can always create a function that kills the flow and try to see when the function is fired.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone wants to do some action/sanatization before saving, he can use **pre_update_option_foo** hook

```html
add_filter( 'pre_update_option_foo', 'myplugin_update_field_foo', 10, 2 );
```

See detail/example in Codex: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/update_option/

Answer (score -5):

You can use WordPress action hook 'save_post' to add actions after the page has been saved. More information and examples of this WordPress hook read http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post

Comment: Is save_post hook suitable for this need? I guess the original question is more related to save settings page (options.php) and not saving a normal post or custom post type in admin. Instead, I find this response more suitable for the original needs: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/79898/trigger-custom-action-when-setting-button-pressed using admin_post hook.